# JavaScript successive split() on variables with dot notation

Tags: javascript, regex, split, built-in

I have this variable:

```
var myVar = "r.object.subobject.variable";
```

I want to add each of the "levels" of this string to an array. My array would contain:

```
"r.object"
"r.object.subobject"
"r.object.subobject.variable"
```

I know I can use JavaScript's split() function with a RegEx, but the one I have keeps returning the whole string. For example, I'm trying:

```
var myArray = myVar.split(/r[.].+/);
```

Thus, `myArray[0]` always comes out as `"r.object.subobject.variable"`.

How can I make `myArray[0] = "r.object"`, `myArray[1] = "r.object.subobject"`, and `myArray[2] = "r.object.subobject.variable"`?

Hopefully I'm only misunderstanding how regular expressions work instead of needing to do some kind of contrived recursion or array concatenation by only separating on the periods.

**Additional Constraints and Background Information**

- The variables I'm checking may have a depth from 1 to an unknown number, so any function should try to determine how many strings to extract. All strings will always start with `r.` (I have a while loop set up for this, and although it will correctly match for a given depth, the split still fails.)
- This operation will occur on thousands or tens of thousands of strings, so speed matters.
- I know bracket notation is a thing, but I cannot use it for my purposes. (The array elements will eventually go back into a specialized AS3 application that doesn't always play nicely with it.)

Comment: You need `r.object.subobject.variable` as a string, not an expression. I.e. `var myVar = 'r.object.subobject.variable'`. Otherwise, you get the value of the expression, not the identifier(s).

Comment: My mistake! These are strings - I'm reading them in from a textarea. I'll update my post with that fix.

Comment: You're regexp is wrong. `.+` will include everything, which is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `myArray[0]` should return an empty string. The expression `/r[.].+/` matches the whole string, thus returning everything after and before the match (empty strings). Notice the `.+` that matches any char repeated once or more times:

```
r.object.subobject.variable
--^                       ^      [1]: matched by r[.]
1 |           2           |
  +------------------------      [2]: matched my .+
```

If you want to split by the dots ("`.`"), use:

```
var myArray = myVar.split(/[.]/);
```

---

**EDIT** As for the updated question, regex can only match a part of the text **once**.

To achieve what you're trying to do, the following code should do:

```js
var myVar = "r.object.subobject.variable";
var mySplit = myVar.split(".");
var myArray = Array();

for (i = 2; i <= mySplit.length; i++) { 
    myArray.push(mySplit.slice(0,i).join("."));
}


document.write(myArray);
```

Comment: Marvelous! The code specified in your edit does the trick for me. 

guest271314's code also achieved the same result, but I understand it less well from a readability perspective. I wish I could award you both the answer, but this one works better for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.split()` with `RegExp` `/\./` , `do.. while` loop , `Array.prototype.slice()` , `Array.prototype.join()` , `Array.prototype.splice()`

```js
var myVar = "r.object.subobject.variable";
var arr = myVar.split(/\./),
  len = arr.length,
  i = 0,
  myArray = [];
do {
  myArray.push(arr.slice(0, i).join("."));
  ++i;
} while (myArray.length <= len);
myArray.splice(0, 2);
console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do get a nice even break like that with regex, maybe if javasacript supported (?R) but doesn't seem like. You could just split it by dots and then concatenate it.

```js
function levels(str) {
  var levels;
  return str.split('.').reduce(function(acc, level, index) {
    if(index > 0) {
       levels = levels + '.' + level
       acc.push(levels);
    } else {
      levels = level;
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(levels('r.object.subobject.variable'), null, '\t');
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```